# How does Monitor.Enter work?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking

I've been doing some investigation to find exactly how Monitor.Enter works internally. I looked through [the code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/monitor.cs#e43dfd2f2524cb91#references) and it seems the actual mechanism for entering is inside an external function:

```
[System.Security.SecuritySafeCritical]
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
private static extern void ReliableEnterTimeout(Object obj, int timeout, ref bool lockTaken);
```

Does anyone know what this function does or what the general mechanism of Monitor.Enter is? How does it know which objects are locked?